# Cardboard, Only Rotate main camera with Unity 5

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

i just start to work with **Google Cardboard** and **Unity 5**, i already have my scene, but when i build my apk and run it into my Android i realzed that when i look around the camera seems to move a little, i just want to look around in my camera animation, but with that extra movement i can see through the floor and other errors, I just want to take a tour of the room.

I already modify **CardboardHead** removing this condition but doesn't work

```
if (trackPosition) {
  Vector3 pos = Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Position;
  if (target == null) {
    transform.localPosition = pos;
  } else {
    transform.position = target.position + target.rotation * pos;
  }
}
```

Do you guys know what C# file i have to modify, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a value called "NeckModelScale" in the Cardboard settings on CardboardMain.  Set it to 0 to get rid of the neck model.

Comment: I feel so stupid u_u, i tried to change this function but it seems not working:

`public float NeckModelScale {
  get {
   return neckModelScale;
  }
  set {
   value = Mathf.Clamp01(value);
   if (!Mathf.Approximately(value, neckModelScale) && device != null) {
    device.SetNeckModelScale(value);
   }
   neckModelScale = value;
  }
 }`

Comment: If you are using the CardboardMain prefab, just select it in the editor and drag the Neck Model Scale slider to 0.